# Allow access across subnets not working

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables, dd-wrt, tomato

I have two routers. One is running DD-WRT and the other is running Tomato. The DD-WRT router is the main router the WAN connection goes through. The Tomato router is for my PIA VPN. DD-WRT is a 192.168.1.x subnet and the Tomato router is 192.168.10.x subnet.

I followed YouTube video and the Tomato has access to and can see the the 192.168.1.x network but the DD-WRT cannot see the 192.168.10.x network.

I've setup a static routing rule through the DD-WRT router and added the following IPtable rule in Tomato:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

Can anyone assist please? I'd like to be able access both subnets seamlessly.

Network Basic Layout:

Modem--->Router 1 (DD-WRT)--->Switch---> [WAN Port] Router 2 ((Tomato(VPN))

Firewall Rules for Router 2:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT |
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT |
iptables -I FORWARD -j ACCEPT
```

Router 2 can see and access Router 1 (& subnet(s)) but Router 1 cannot.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm experiencing a very similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

DD-WRT and Tomato are very complex software. There are many possible configuration combinations that can cause the situation you're having. A network topology diagram (at least in ASCII form) goes a long way.

Anyway, I think you may have connected the WAN port of the Tomato router, which is in Gateway mode by default, to the LAN (switch) port of the DD-WRT router. Tomato does NAT on the WAN interface in Gateway mode. This explains why the static routing entry on the DD-WRT router is not doing anything.

You have two options:

1. Switch the Tomato router to Router mode, which disables NAT on the
   WAN interface. This can be done by going to Advanced > Routing in
   the Web interface.
2. Remove the Ethernet connection from the Tomato router's WAN port and
   connect it to its LAN port. You will have to set up VLAN on the
   DD-WRT router if you want to have two separate subnets. Only a
   handful of home routers support VLAN.

Comment: I tried putting it in router mode and still no go. If I go through the LAN then I wont be able to have traffic going through the VPN. I have PIA and want a separate router that forces all traffic through the VPN.

Comment: Modem--->Router 1 (DD-WRT)--->Switch---> [WAN Port] Router 2 ((Tomato(VPN)) 

That is basically the layout. Router 2 can access and see everything but Router 1 cannot. 

Firewall Rules for Router 2:
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT |
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT |
iptables -I FORWARD -j ACCEPT